# File.Move() rename not working

Tags: c#

My app takes "unclean" file names and "cleans" them up.  "Unclean" file names contain characters like @, #, ~, +, %, etc.  The "cleaning" process replaces those chars with "".  However, I found that if there are two files in the same folder that, after a cleaning, will have the same name, my app does not rename either file.  (I.e. ##test.txt and ~test.txt will both be named test.txt after the cleaning).

Therefore, I put in a loop that basically checks to see if the file name my app is trying to rename already exists in the folder.  However, I tried running this and it would not rename all the files.  Am I doing something wrong?

Here's my code:

```
        public void FileCleanup(List<string> paths)
    {
        string regPattern = (@"[~#&!%+{}]+");
        string replacement = "";

        Regex regExPattern = new Regex(regPattern);
        List<string> existingNames = new List<string>();
        StreamWriter errors = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Documents and Settings\joe.schmoe\Desktop\SharePointTesting\Errors.txt");
        StreamWriter resultsofRename = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Documents and Settings\joe.schmoe\Desktop\SharePointTesting\Results of File Rename.txt");

        var filesCount = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        string replaceSpecialCharsWith = "_";

        foreach (string files2 in paths)

            try
            {
                string filenameOnly = Path.GetFileName(files2);
                string pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(files2);
                string sanitizedFileName = regExPattern.Replace(filenameOnly, replacement);
                string sanitized = Path.Combine(pathOnly, sanitizedFileName);
                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(sanitized))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Move(files2, sanitized);
                    resultsofRename.Write("Path: " + pathOnly + " / " + "Old File Name: " + filenameOnly + "New File Name: " + sanitized + "\r\n" + "\r\n");   
                }

                else 
                {
                    existingNames.Add(sanitized);
                    foreach (string names in existingNames)
                    {

                        string sanitizedPath = regExPattern.Replace(names, replaceSpecialCharsWith);
                        if (filesCount.ContainsKey(sanitizedPath))
                        {
                            filesCount[names]++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            filesCount.Add(sanitizedPath, 1);
                        }

                        string newFileName = String.Format("{0},{1}, {2}", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sanitizedPath),
                        filesCount[sanitizedPath] != 0
                        ? filesCount[sanitizedPath].ToString()
                        : "",
                        Path.GetExtension(sanitizedPath));

                        string newFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(sanitizedPath), newFileName);
                        System.IO.File.Move(names, newFileName);

                    }
                 }
              }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //write to streamwriter

            }

    }

}
```

Anybody have ANY idea why my code won't rename duplicate files uniquely?

Comment: EDIT:  Fixed code as per user comments -- however it's still not renaming the duplicate file names...any ideas?  Am i still messing this up?

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but your list of invalid characters is somewhat off.  You should be using `Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars` and `Path.GetInvalidPathChars` to determine what's allowed on the system.  Otherwise you're going be disallowing valid characters like `{`, but allowing invalid characters like `>` and `\t`.  Also, consider that these functions will allow your code to operate correctly in non-Windows environments (e.g. Silverlight on OS X; Mono.)

Comment: well, i'm just trying to get rid of characters in File names that are invalid for SharePoint migrations.  Since users can't use /\:*?|"<> in file names, it's less of a concern.
This app is to be used ONLY on a windows platform also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the problem pointed out by Sjoerd, it appears that you are checking to see if the file exists and if it **does exist** you move it.  Your if statement should be

```
     if (!System.IO.File.Exists(sanitized))
     {
         ...
     }    
     else 
     {
         foreach (string names in existingNames)
             {
                 ...    
             }
         }
     }
```

Update:

I agree that you should split the code up into smaller methods.  It will help you identify which pieces are working and which aren't.  That being said, I would get rid of the existingNames list.  It is not needed because you have the filesCount Dictionary.  Your else clause would then look something like this:

```
     if (filesCount.ContainsKey(sanitized))
     {
         filesCount[sanitized]++;
     }
     else
     {
       filesCount.Add(sanitized, 1);
     }

     string newFileName = String.Format("{0}{1}.{2}", 
                                        Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sanitized),
                                        filesCount[sanitized].ToString(),
                                        Path.GetExtension(sanitized));

     string newFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(sanitized), newFileName);
     System.IO.File.Move(files2, newFileName);
```

Please note that I changed your String.Format method call.  You had some commas and spaces in there that looked incorrect for building a path, although I could be missing something in your implementation.  Also, in the Move I changed the first argument from "names" to "files2".

Comment: in this code, is the sanitizedPath supposed to be sanitized from my code or am i missing somethign?

Comment: Sorry it should have been sanitized, not sanitizedPath. I updated the code.

Answer (score 3):

- You do `foreach (string names in existingNames)`, but `existingNames` is empty.
- You have your `if (System.IO.File.Exists(sanitized))` backwards: it makes up a new name if the file doesn't exist, instead of when it exists.
- You make a string `newFileName`, but still use `sanitizedPath` instead of `newFileName` to do the renaming.
- The second parameter to `filesCount.Add(sanitizedPath, 0)` should be 1 or 2. After all, you have then encountered your second file with the same name.
- If `filesCount[sanitizedPath]` equals 0, you don't change the filename at all, so you overwrite the existing file.

Comment: ok i edited the code--however it's still not uniquely renaming the duplicate file.  is there anything else wrong with it?

Answer (score 2):

A good way to make the code less messy would be to split it to methods as logical blocks.

`FindUniqueName(string filePath, string fileName);`
The method would prefix the `fileName` with a character, until the fileName is unique withing the `filePath`.

`MoveFile(string filePath, string from, string to);`
The method would use the `FindUniqueName` method if the file already exists.

It would be way easier to test the cleanup that way.

Also you should check if a file actually **requires renaming**:

```
if (String.Compare(sanitizedFileName, filenameOnly, true) != 0)
  MoveFile(pathOnly, fileNameOnly, sanitizedFileName);

private string FindUniqueName(string fileDirectory, string from, string to)
{
    string fileName = to;

    // There most likely won't be that many files with the same name to reach max filename length.
    while (File.Exists(Path.Combine(fileDirectory, fileName)))
    {
        fileName = "_" + fileName;
    }

    return fileName;
}

private void MoveFile(string fileDirectory, string from, string to)
{
    to = FindUniqueName(fileDirectory, from, to);

    File.Move(Path.Combine(fileDirectory, from), Path.Combine(fileDirectory, to));
}
```

Comment: where in the code do i add this?  i'm sorry for all the questions, i'm VERY new to C#

Comment: The first two lines should go just below the `sanitizedFileName` declaration (it will rename the file `fileNameOnly` to `sanitizedFileName`).
The two methods (`FindUniqueName` and `MoveFile`) can go anywhere in the class.
It is just basic functionality - you can add more when you see it is working.